# Save coordinates to database and then do a range search

Tags: laravel, vue.js, geolocation, coordinates, tomtom

I’m using the TomTom API to find the coordinates of some places and store them into a database. What I’m trying to do now is doing a range research on only those locations.
Let’s say I input 10km of range and a place, I’d expect to see the list of places I’ve saved in my db that are inside that range. How can I do that?
I’m using Laravel and Vue

Comment: Hey did my answer work for you? If so do not forget to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a migration for your places and add these 2 columns for your lat and long:

```
        $table->decimal('latitude', 11, 8)->nullable();
        $table->decimal('longitude', 11, 8)->nullable();
```

After that you can store your locations inside your db.

Then you can use **whereBetween** condition in your query:

```
$locations = Location::whereBetween('latitude', [1, 100])->whereBetween('longitude', [200, 300])->get();
```

WhereBetween condition accepts 2 arguments, column name and min-max values respectively.